# How do I fix bad font rendering in web broswers?

Tags: firefox, fonts

This just happened today - the fonts in my web browers' UI as well as content looks awful. I'm running an up to date version of Ubuntu 15.04. The browsers affected are chromium and Firefox. Strangely, the fonts in all the other applications are perfect. However Java based applications such as Android Studio also have the same ugly, un-antialiased fonts now.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

It is also worth noting that I had downloaded and installed the fontfix package for Java applications.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this looks like an antialiasing issue. Easiest solution is to install Unity Tweak Tool, open it, click "Fonts", and set antialiasing to RGBA, Hinting: Slight.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve my problem for firefox or chrome